# How to let Raspberry 4 B stop spinning the external hard disk when there is no write or read request?

Tags: pi-4, hard-drive, power-management, storage

Device:

Raspberry 4 B;

OS: Arch Linux ARM;

Interface: USB 3.0

I have a Raspberry and external HDD, all the stuff's details are above.

I want to automatically suspend my hard disk (in order to saving power and make HDD lifespan longer). And when there is new IO request, the HDD will start again. But There isn't any GNOME or KDE software on the platform.

What software should I use or what configuration should I set to make My Raspberry 4 act as what I described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe can apparently be achieved through installation and configuration of the `hdparm` utility ([ref](https://www.htpcguides.com/spin-down-and-manage-hard-drive-power-on-raspberry-pi/)).

You might check the Arch Linux repo for this package, or you might try posting this same question on the [Arch Linux New User forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewforum.php?id=23).

Comment: Thanks for you hinting, but are you sure it is `hdparm` not `sdparm`. Because all those external hard drive is relatively new.

Comment: If you'll follow the link in my answer, you can read all about `hdparm`. There is a package called `sdparm` also, but I don't know what it's used for.